# Is there a way to look into the resources used by base android libraries?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-view, android-assets, android-resources

I recently started making a month view similar to Android 4.0's Calendar View.

I also recently found a cool eclipse plugin by using which we can step into Android base classes, the plugin can be found [here](http://www.androidpolice.com/2011/12/22/gold-for-android-developers-add-aosp-source-code-to-eclipse-with-the-android-sources-plugin/)

I am now able to read the class implementation of Calendar View but there are many resources used in it like

```
mFirstDayOfWeek = attributesArray.getInt(R.styleable.CalendarView_firstDayOfWeek,
            LocaleData.get(Locale.getDefault()).firstDayOfWeek);
```

So I am basically trying to make a custom view by reading Calendar Views class and I am confused of the properties used by it. I know that they are declared in attrs.xml file but I wanted to have a look at the implementation by Google.

My question is can we also have a look at how those styleable attributes are declared?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the end, the best way is still to [download the android source](http://source.android.com/source/downloading.html). You'll have access to all source files, resources, drawables, etc.

Comment: true but wouldn't it be nice if there was a way to look at resources too, because they are there somewhere in the source code..
Anyways thanks for the answer:)